# ios: Drag a name of state/country on Map image then related state colour will be changed

Tags: ios, imageview

I have Image view which shows the country map. when i am dragging the name of state and drop over that state, then that state color will be changed, and if drop on wrong state then name will be go to their place.

I am new in ios, Please help me how can i implement this.

Thanks in Advance..!!

Comment: do you have one image and you want to change part of an image if you place label on top of right image....?

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

If you have one image and you want to identify different part of the the country i.e. states then you need to do some calculation which will recognize the the small part of Image view as different state(Hard part) and then you can draw or mask that rect with different color(Easy part) or to move label back to its position(easy part).

**Recognizing a state from an image** You have to make calculations which can create a bezier path for each state that will be became a border of state and anything inside that path will be one state. This part became complicated due to different screen sizes, but you can set some ratios to figure that out, or you can add pre calculated points for each state and load them in device dependent on screen size and then map that on the image view.

**Coloring State Area** When you will drag drop a label on image you will know to which state this label belong and check if label interesting major portion of a state or its is inside that area you can create a shape layer with that state bezier path and then add over an image view.

**Alternative** You can slice your image with photoshop on bases of states and then you can add those images and join them, add auto layout to layout them properly or you can do that with code, then you will have one tile per state and you can easily find if label is drop over right state or not and also easily color a state.